# errors converting eregi_replace into preg_replace

Tags: php

How do I change `eregi_replace` in this code to `preg_replace()`?

This is the original code:

```
$title = eregi_replace('</?[a-z][a-z0-9]*[^<>]*>', '', $title );
```

Do I just need to overwrite `eregi_replace` with `preg_replace` or do I need to do more?

I tried this and some variations:

```
$title = preg_match('#<\/?[a-z][a-z0-9]*[^<>]*>#', '', $title );
```

When title is submited it turns into 0 and the value is lost.

Comment: It seems you are not using `preg_replace()`.

Comment: Why would you change `eregi_replace` to `preg_match`?  Change it from `eregi_replace` to `preg_replace`.

Comment: Use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) not `preg_match`.

Comment: If you're doing this conversion, why not convert to using an actual HTML parser instead of doing it with regexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I shall make an easy answer that other users don't take time to reply:

eregi_replace() uses [POSIX regex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) and preg_replace() uses Perl Compatible Regular Expressions [PCRE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php), they can have differences.

But in your case with a good formed regex, it remains the same. It removes all HTML tags in the title text:

#### Old regex:

```
$title = eregi_replace('</?[a-z][a-z0-9]*[^<>]*>', '', $title );
```

#### New regex:

```
$title = preg_replace('#</?[a-z][a-z0-9]*[^<>]*>#i', '', $title );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this realy explains it for me